# PHP MySql Select Query does not return updated records

Tags: php, mysql, caching

I have a simple php site that uses a mysql database.

Whenever I attempt to update or insert a record, the database does reflect the change, however when I attempt to run the select query a second time, it returns a result set as if the update or insert never took place.

It seems as if it is caching the results. When I clear the web browser's cache and cookies and reload the page, the select statement does return the updated records.

Any suggestions would certainly be appreciated.
Thanks a lot !

Upon page load, selectplayers is called and will return player A and B.
I then call deleteplayer to remove B and the record is indeed removed from the database.
I call selectplayers a second time and it still returns player A and B.
If I clear the cache and reload the page, it returns only player A.

```
function selectplayers() {
       $db = new db("mysql-t","user","password","database");
       $id = $db->escape($_REQUEST["id"]);
       $db->execute("SELECT name FROM players WHERE id=$id");
       $db->close();
       //echo result set to page
}

function deleteplayer() {
       $db = new db("mysql-t","user","password","database");
       $id = $db->escape($_REQUEST["id"]);
       $db->execute("DELETE FROM players WHERE id=$id");
       $db->close();
}
```

The headers are as follows:
    header('Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: no-cache');
    header('Expires: 0');

Comment: Maybe a problem with transactions?

Comment: I've included the code if that helps at all.
I am not using transactions. The inserts and updates do hit the database and are permanent, it's just the select statements appears incorrect the second time. Thanks for replies!

Answer (score 0):

Are you using transaction, if you are, then you may need to commit after insert. If you don't it will rollback to previous value. without code its harder to guess, i think this may be the issue.